# SQL Server 2019 - add day in date with time component

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, sql-server-2019

I want to add 1 day to date with time component.
My date is say for eg.

```
2020-09-10 18:30:00.000'
```

and I want to add 24 hours i.e expected output is

```
2020-09-11 18:30:00.000
```

I wrote `SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, '2020-09-10 18:30:00.000'), 1)` but this does not show the time component.

How to add date with time component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `datediff()` in your attempt. And according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql), the date is the third argument of the `dateadd()` function.

```
select dateadd(day, 1, convert(datetime, '2020-09-10 18:30:00.000') );
```

Output:

```
2020-09-11 18:30:00.000
```

Comment: . . The conversion to `datetime` is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server is really flexible about recognizing date formats, and will happily understand your string as a date if you put in within a date function. So, no need for explicit conversion from string to date, you can just do:

```
dateadd(day, 1, '2020-09-10 18:30:00.000')
```